# Oauth login doesn't work, displays: [File of type 'application/vnd.microsoft.card.oauth']

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

When I implement login and test it in the bot emulator, or works great:

[image]

But when I test it using the web chat, it displays something weird instead:

[image]

Why is it different on the web chat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For web chat, in the Azure portal the webchat tab is using an older version of webchat that will not render the cards, the same is true if you are using the iFrame version of webchat. You will need to use another method of webchat if you would like to see the card rendered. You can find different ways to utilize webchat [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#how-to-add-web-chat-to-your-website)